# Javascript API for Link prefetching

Tags: javascript, html, rfc, prefetch, preloading

There are a lot of answers how to preload assets with JS - in parallel or consecutive modes, with AJAX or JS objects, etc. But most of them put pressure on a current connection: if a site has other assets like visible images this approach could have negative impact on site loading.

Is there JS API that implements the same [Link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ) features link tag/header has? To load assets in the moments when a connection is idle, to stop and to restart them. The thing that seems possible to be utilized for these needs is [TCPSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket) but it is **Firefox OS** only.

*Example:* I have 2 types of galleries. The 1st one - **Gallery A** - with previews of images and the 2nd one - **Gallery B** - with full-size versions for the same images. While a user is viewing the previews I'm doing standard preloading of the previews for **Gallery A**. And also I want to add the full-size images from **Gallery B** to the prefetching queue.

Comment: Could also load all images within a `template` , display larger full-size images from within same document, without making additional requests to server ? Or, load full-size images, resize full-size images within same document to display as previews, display full-size images at user action ? This approach would load only full-size images once, without requesting duplicates of same images from server ?

Comment: There's no way in the world I would visit a site that did this, once I found out.  My data cap is precious to me.  I'm sure it is to many other people as well.